# Why is the glare node never working?

Tags: node-editor, glare

[image: this is my node setup]

So, I am making a pitch-black humanoid model for a game. I have tried several versions of the glare node and none of them work. Does it not work in cycles?

Comment: Glare best works with emissions shades, a black render its not the best option

Comment: Hello. Do you have an example of what you want to achieve ? The glare node basically blurs out the most bright parts of an image, I don't see how you would make it work in a pitch black image.

Comment: Tips why your setup cannot work: the _Glare_ node only works on emissions higher than the _Threshold_ value: yours is set to 1, black has an emission of 0, so with 0 < 1:  no glare effect. Then it adds either _Streaks_ or _Fog Glow_ or _Ghosts_ to the image resulting from the emission (the part that exceeds the _Threshold_) multiplied by a factor x, but even when lowering the threshold to 0, with a black image this would result in 0 · x = 0: no glare effect. Stupid question: what kind of glare effect do you expect from something that is pitch black?